# Application of Leibniz Integral Rule

Tags: calculus

The textbook asserts the following citing Leibniz's Integral Rule:

[image]

However, I am unable to see what exactly was done. I understand Leibniz's rule, but I am just not able to see it in the above two cases. I am not even sure what $I$ and $J$ is being integrate with respect to.

Some insight would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a typo in the integral of $I'$. The upper limit should be $x$ and not $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is simply the Fundamental theorem of calculus. If $$f(t)=\int_0^t F(u)du$$ then
$$I(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt \Rightarrow I'(x)=f(x) = \int_0^x F(u)du$$

For the second one, let $$g(x,u)=(x-u)F(u)$$ If F is continuous, then so are $g$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\equiv F$. By Leibniz's integral rule,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^z g(x,u) du = \int_0^z \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,u)du$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}J(x)=\int_0^z F(u)du$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For $I'(x)$ use the fundamental theorem of calculus. For $J'(x)$ use the fact that $$J(x) = x\int_0^z F(u)\,du - \int_0^z u F(u)\,du$$

Comment: It should be a minus sign, but I can't edit it unless I change 5 more characters

Comment: @aaaaa Good point.. silly typo

Comment: This answers avoids using Leibnitz Integral Rule and it's still easy enough.